# I am getting an error in adding a row in invoice_line_item after implementng the following trigger :- Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

```
I am getting an error in adding a row in invoice_line_item after implementing the following trigger :-  Sub query returns more than 1 row
```

I cant figure what is wrong in this

```
delimiter $$
create trigger hey before insert on invoice_line_item
 for each row 
begin set new.rate=
                   (select P.rate 
                    from product P,invoice_line_item I 
                    where I.product_id=P.product_id);
set new.value=new.rate*new.quantity;
end; 
$$
```

Comment: Use `{}` button in editor to format code properly.

Comment: Your subquery returns more than 1 row and so the error.

Comment: I'm sure you want to add a condition, so that the rate is the rate for this special item to your where clause. Btw I would rather rewrite your subselect with an explicit join and then add the appropriate where clause for this row.

Comment: the product_id is the primary key for product.hence the subquery should not produce a table with more than one row

Comment: Why it shouldn't? Have you included any filtering? I don't see though. try adding an extra condition like `P.product_id = 12`

Comment: at every insert in invoice_line_item, i dont want to enter the rate which are already listed in a table called product. hence i implemented a trigger that will copy the rate of that particular product_id(foreign key in invoice_line_item) listed in the product table.

Comment: There's no implicit filtering on any values of your new row. It's just a simple join with all rows that this join produces. If your invoice_line_item table contains a column product_id, that references the product table, then you got to include this condition too. See the answer of Rahul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner query:

```
select P.rate 
from product P,invoice_line_item I 
where I.product_id=P.product_id
```

just executing that by itself would seemingly return more than one value - in a set statement you have to be assigning a column to a single value.

Given:

```
Product
-----
productId PK
productName
rate

Invoice_line_item
-----
invoiceId PK
productId FK

productId    productName    rate
1            foo            500
2            bar            525

invoiceId    productId
1000         1
1001         2
```

Running your query from above would return:

```
rate
-----
500
525
```

you have nothing limiting which productId should be pulled for rate, you're just stating pull all rates for all products that also exist in the invoice table.

To fix your problem, you would need to update your query to pull a rate for a specific productId

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but try adding an extra condition in your subquery to filter out the `product_id` like below. Also, notice that I have changed your subquery to use explicit join syntax rather.

```
select P.rate 
from product P
join invoice_line_item I on I.product_id=P.product_id
where P.product_id = new.product_id
```

Comment: umm join is not required though..instead of I.product_id it should have been new.product_id.